# CellContentClick sometimes not functioning

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, click

Im having trouble with my `CellContentClick` event. sometimes, it's not functioning. This is my code:

```
private void studentDGV_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.studentDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                MessageBox.Show((String)row.Cells["StudentNo"].Value.ToString()+"");
            }
        }
```

I remember that when I was programming with vb.net, I had problems with this event too. So I use another event `SelectionChanged`, but I dont know how to implement it in c#.

this is my vb.net code:

```
'This function was called whenever you change the cell Cursor
    Private Sub SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DGV.SelectionChanged
        ' Update the labels to reflect changes to the selection.
        Try
            Dim que As String = Me.DGV.Rows(Me.DGV.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
            changeAccessCB.Text = SQL.getAccess(que)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Can any one please help me to write this code into C#? If possible, please enumerate the steps how to do this.

Comment: As the name implies it will happen __only when actual content__ (as opposed to empty space) is getting hit. Use `CellClick` instead if you can't guarantee that! Don't use `SelectionChanged` as it will be triggered with __any__ changes including de-selecting..

Comment: wow. it works. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    if (IsANonHeaderLinkCell(e))
    {
        MoveToLinked(e);
    }
    else if (IsANonHeaderButtonCell(e))
    {
        PopulateSales(e);
    }
}

private void MoveToLinked(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string employeeId;
    object value = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
    if (value is DBNull) { return; }

    employeeId = value.ToString();
    DataGridViewCell boss = RetrieveSuperiorsLastNameCell(employeeId);
    if (boss != null)
    {
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = boss;
    }
}

private bool IsANonHeaderLinkCell(DataGridViewCellEventArgs cellEvent)
{
    if (DataGridView1.Columns[cellEvent.ColumnIndex] is
        DataGridViewLinkColumn &&
        cellEvent.RowIndex != -1)
    { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}

private bool IsANonHeaderButtonCell(DataGridViewCellEventArgs cellEvent)
{
    if (DataGridView1.Columns[cellEvent.ColumnIndex] is
        DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
        cellEvent.RowIndex != -1)
    { return true; }
    else { return (false); }
}

private DataGridViewCell RetrieveSuperiorsLastNameCell(string employeeId)
{

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow) { return null; }
        if (row.Cells[ColumnName.EmployeeId.ToString()].Value.ToString().Equals(employeeId))
        {
            return row.Cells[ColumnName.LastName.ToString()];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```